# How to retrieve specific fields using mongoose when using Model.find() function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to retrieve specific fields from a database named "fruitDB", and the table that I'm trying to retrieve is from the "fruits" table. As of right now I am able to retrieve all the fields of the documents from that "fruits" table using mongoose.

What I want is to retrieve specific fields from that table rather than retrieving all the fields. How can I do it? And by the way, we are not able to use call back functions in the latest mongoose version anymore.

Here is what I have tried so far,

```
import mongoose, { mongo } from "mongoose";

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB");

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String,
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Pretty solid as a fruit.",
});

const kiwi = new Fruit({
  name: "Kiwi",
  score: 10,
  review: "The best fruit!",
});

const orange = new Fruit({
  name: "Orange",
  score: 4,
  review: "Too sour for me",
});

const banana = new Fruit({
  name: "Banana",
  score: 3,
  review: "Weird texture",
});

try {
  for await (const fruitAll of Fruit.find()) {
  console.log(fruitAll);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

In the above code, it'll display all the items with all the fields.

I tried using the below code to get the fields with names, but I get an error saying call back functions are no longer supported.

```
Fruit.find(function(err, fruits) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        fruits.forEach(function(fruit){
            console.log(fruit.name);
        });
    }
});
```

If you have any suggestions if there are better ODMs than Mongoose, feel free to mention it. I'm still new for using mongoose and mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I just now figured it out, when going through the mongoose docs. Here's what I adjusted in the code.

```
try {
  for await (const fruitAll of Fruit.find({}, 'name')) {
    console.log(fruitAll.name);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: No no dude. You will kill your app/server doing this. Imagine you had hundreds of thousands or even millions or documents. This will run a for loop on all the documents in your returned hits.

Comment: I did this just for a really small database. But I would like to know the implementation for a bigger database. So can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Using mongoose is a good choice for CRUD operations on your database. The most common way to leverage mongoose in Node is by taking query parameters or updates/inserts from your front end and using Models to execute the queries/updates/inserts. The data is then passed to a server-side templating package such as ejs/handlebars/pug and that is where you do the looping to display your data. Alternatively you can send the data as JSON to a front-end and let React/Vue handle the looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select` method to only select the fields you want returned in the query:

```js
const fruits = await Fruit.find({}).select('name');
console.log(fruits);
```

See [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) for reference.